# how to add same onchange events to different select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `'change'` events to 4 select boxes. I have done it using `bind()`.
But I want to call different functions on change of each select box.
Say **function1()** on change event of `SelectBox1`...

> How should I do it?

I am **new** to `javascript` & `jquery`, so please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your HTML like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectBox1">
</select>

<select id="selectBox2">
</select>

<select id="selectBox3">
</select>

<select id="selectBox4">
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('select[id^=selectBox]').on('change', function() {

    // to get the id of current selectBox
    var selectId = this.id;

    if(selectId == 'selectBox1') {
        function1();
    } else if(selecId == 'selectBox2') {
       function2();
    }
    // and so on
});
```

---

#### Some more

```
$('select[id^=selectBox]').on('change', function() {
     
        // to get the selected value
        var value = $.trim( this.value ); // $.trim() used to remove space
                                          // from beginning and end
                                          // you may not use

        // to get selected option text
        var optText = $('option:selected', this).text()


        // to get the selectedIndex
        var selIndex = this.selectedIndex;
        // OR
        var selIndex = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
});
```

---

#### Note

Here, `select[id^=selectBox]` get select boxes, whose `id` start with `selectBox`. You may have something different `id`.

**[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change)** used for bind the event to those select box.

Read more about

- **[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)**
- **[jQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)**
- **[$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**
- **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

Comment: @user1441513 it would be better to use `.on()` rather than bind.

Answer (score 0):

you can set an specific attribute for each select so:

```
<select id="selectBox1" val='1'>
</select>

<select id="selectBox2" val='2'>
</select>

<select id="selectBox3" val='3'>
</select>

<select id="selectBox4" val='4'>
</select>
```

and then bind onchange event like this:

```
  $("select").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr("val");
        if (val == '1')
            {
                //logic for first select change
            }
        else if (val == '2')
            {
                //logic for second select change
            }
        else if (val == '3')
            {
                //logic for third select change
            }

        // and so on...
   });
```

hope that helps.